# How to DRY up a test case repeated in multiple contexts?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I monkeypatched URI and wrote tests for it:

```
describe URI do
  describe '.sanitize_domain' do
    let(:expectation) { 'toolbar.google.com' }
    subject { described_class.sanitize_domain(url) }

    context 'when url is correct' do
      context 'when url misses both http and www prefixes' do
        let(:url) { 'toolbar.google.com/public' }
        it { is_expected.to eq(expectation) }
      end

      context 'when url contains www' do
        let(:url) { 'www.toolbar.google.com/public' }
        it { is_expected.to eq(expectation) }
      end

      context 'when url contains https' do
        let(:url) { 'https://toolbar.google.com/public' }
        it { is_expected.to eq(expectation) }
      end

      context 'when url contains both http and www' do
        let(:url) { 'http://www.toolbar.google.com/public' }
        it { is_expected.to eq(expectation) }
      end

      context 'when multiple urls are given' do
        let(:url) { 'http://www.toolbar.google.com/Default.asp, http://www.toolbar.google.com/' }
        it { is_expected.to eq(expectation) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see, `it { is_expected.to eq(expectation) }` is repeated in each context.

I think there is a solution to dry it up a bit. 
I could use shared_examples here, but IMHO it would be overkill to do that for a single `it` and readability would decrease.

I tried to extract `expectation` to `before(:context) { it { is_expected } }` but the `it` keyword isn't available inside `before` block. Here is the error message from that attempt:

> `it` is not available from within an example (e.g. an `it` block) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc). It is only available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block).

Answer (score 1):

```
inner_contextes_urls = [
  ['when url misses both http and www prefixes', 'toolbar.google.com/public'],
  ['when url contains www', 'www.toolbar.google.com/public']
  # ...
]
inner_contextes_urls.each do |(title, url)|
  context "#{title}" do
    let(:url) { "#{url}" }
    it { is_expected.to eq(expectation) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For tests that are both minimal and readable, just extract a method:

```
describe URI do
  describe '.sanitize_domain' do
    context 'when url is correct' do
      it 'sanitizes a URL without http and www prefixes' do
        expect_sanitized_domain_to_handle 'toolbar.google.com/public'
      end

      it 'sanitizes a URL which contains www' do
        expect_sanitized_domain_to_handle 'www.toolbar.google.com/public'
      end

      it 'sanitizes a URL which contains https' do
        expect_sanitized_domain_to_handle 'https://toolbar.google.com/public'
      end

      it 'sanitizes a URL which contains both http and www' do
        expect_sanitized_domain_to_handle 'https://www.toolbar.google.com/public'
      end

      it 'sanitizes a string containing multiple URLs' do
        expect_sanitized_domain_to_handle 'http://www.toolbar.google.com/Default.asp, http://www.toolbar.google.com/'
      end

      def expect_sanitized_domain_to_handle(url)
        expect(URL.sanitize_domain(url)).to eq('toolbar.google.com')
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Or, to get the expected return value into the test where you can see it, and change it if you need a test with a different return value:

```
it 'sanitizes a URL from a different site' do
  expect_sanitized_domain given: 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331374/the-same-test-case-for-few-contexts-in-rspec-how-to-dry-it',
    to_return: 'stackoverflow.com'
end

def expect_sanitized_domain(given:, to_return:)
  expect(URL.sanitize_domain(given)).to eq(to_return)
end
```